# How to parse string date format to kendo date

Tags: javascript, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I have this date string copied from postgres database - 2000/12/22 03:50:14

I want to format it to something like this using kendo - Friday 22 Dec, 2000 03:50AM.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kKhm3/644/

CODE:

```
var date1 = kendo.parseDate("2000/12/22", "yyyy/MM/dd");

$("#result2").text(kendo.toString(date1, "dddd dd MMM, yyyy hh:mmtt"));
```

Comment: What is the problems with your JSFiddle, is not doing what you expected? The only thing that I see is that you are not reading hours, minutes and seconds but other than that works fine. Using hours, minutes and seconds is here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kKhm3/645/